# Should I use a comma before it's in a follow-on independent clause?

Tags: commas, run-on-sentence

1. I just want to gulp it down it's that good.
2. I just want to gulp it down, it's that good.

Wondering about using a comma here...

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are run-on sentences (see [this article from Walden University](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/runonsentences)). Your first version consists of two independent clauses that have not been joined at all. In your second version, they are joined only by a comma (a "comma splice," as that article explains).

In formal writing, neither of these is valid; you would want to use an em-dash:

> I just want to gulp it down—it's that good.

Comment: I came—I saw—I conquered. I'd say the statement is used in formal contexts, but usually with commas (occasionally beefed up to semicolons). The comma splice is gradually losing its stigma (not in all cases, of course). But 'gulp it down' is hardly a 'formal' marker.